# FutureWarning: Arrays of bytes/strings is being converted to decimal numbers if dtype='numeric'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deprecation-warning, streamlit

```
FutureWarning: Arrays of bytes/strings is being converted to decimal numbers if 
dtype='numeric'. This behavior is deprecated in 0.24 and will be removed in 1.1 (renaming of 0.26). 
Please convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.
```

Please what does this mean? I have been trying to deploy my model  but this keeps coming up when I run it

Answer (score 6):

I believe that either your `targets` or `features` are not in numeric format.

For example:

```
['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'] #  non-numeric format
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] #  numeric format
```

You can fix this by using `numpy` or a for loop as:

```
a = ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'] #  non-numeric format
b = np.array(a, dtype=float) #  convert using numpy
c = [float(i) for i in a] #  convert with for loop
```

As I understood, `sklearn` will convert non-numeric arrays to numeric so it works anyways, but judging by the warning that will not be longer the case going forward.

Next time please include your code or part of it so it is easier to help you.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. This clarified the problem for me

Comment: This worked out for me. I converted the series to a list and passed it `np.array` specifying `dtype=float`. That solved the issue.