# Why pd.concat() of two dataframe leads to FutureWarning: Behavior when concatenating bool-dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

List item

I want to concatenate two dataframe with `pd.concat()` as below:

```
if (not df_1.empty) | (not df_2.empty):
    new_df= pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

It returns the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: Behavior when concatenating bool-dtype and numeric-dtype arrays is deprecated; in a future version these will cast to object dtype (instead of coercing bools to numeric values). To retain the old behavior, explicitly cast bool-dtype arrays to numeric dtype.
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664706/futurewarning-arrays-of-bytes-strings-is-being-converted-to-decimal-numbers-if) question as well, but here I have a `DataFrame` which contains `str` and different types of numbers (`int`, `float`). What should I do in this case?

This is the sample data of each dataframe:
df_1:

| dateTime | entryRate | stop | limit | amount | stdLotds | currencyName | Buy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/11/2022 11:24 | 1.31006 | 0 | 0 | 5000 | 0.05 | GBPUSD | True |
| 3/11/2022 11:24 | 1.31007 | 0 | 0 | 1000 | 0.01 | GBPUSD | False |
| 3/11/2022 11:11 | 1.79134 | 0 | 1.78448 | 2000 | 0.02 | GBPAUD | True |

df_2:

| dateTime | entryRate | stop | limit | amount | stdLotds | currencyName | Buy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/14/2022 10:24 | 1.31012 | 0 | 0 | 5000 | 0.05 | GBPUSD | False |
| 3/11/2022 12:25 | 1.31017 | 0 | 0 | 3000 | 0.09 | EURUSD | False |
| 3/14/2022 10:00 | 1.79114 | 0 | 1.78448 | 2000 | 0.03 | AUDCAD | True |

Comment: Please include sample data so others may try to re-create problem and better understand how to help

Comment: It is saying one of your columns in one of the df is defined as `bool`, while the same column on the other df is defined as `numeric`. Have you checked your dfs if this is the case? If yes, you should do as the warning says and ensure the columns have same data types before concatenating.

Comment: I face this warning even one of the dataframe is empty!
Does it meaningful?

Comment: Why are you concatenating if one of your dataframes is empty? Is that not what this line >>
    if (not df_1.empty) | (not df_2.empty): <<
checks for?

Comment: I use this line in a program which runs on a VPS regularly. So, in some cases one of them may be empty. However, the program has a problem for this concatenation. Either for empty or full dataframes.

Comment: try to do printouts of df.info() and post them both in the question

Comment: Good idea. I have done that. In some cases columns' type of one dataframe are object and in the other one is float64. Does it make problem for pd.concat()?

Comment: Yes. Try using df["Column Name"].map(float) - > if you are mapping from object to float, if mapping from float to object, use str instead of float

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242908/discussion-between-v-nouri-and-rasmus).

Answer (score 5):

I got this warning in an unexpected location when concatenating a list of dataframes that all contained the same columns with consistent datatypes across frames. The reason the warning appeared was that some frames had 0 rows and therefore were not assigned datatypes in the same way as the other frames. I stopped receiving the error after filtering out empty dataframes before concatenating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
if (not df_1.empty) & (not df_2.empty):
    new_df= pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

i.e. and (&) in stead of or (|)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does happen, despite null values not being present in the original data and even after applying fillna(0) operation. I think using Warnings Module might help. You may try the following:

````
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', 'DeprecationWarning')```
````

Answer (score 0):

More dynamically:

```
ListMyDfs = ['df_1', 'df_2', 'df_3']
 
df = pd.DataFrame()
 
for MyDf in ListMyDfs:
    if globals()[MyDf].shape[0] > 0:
        df = pd.concat([df, globals()[MyDf]], axis=0)
```